# What chakra natures does Naruto have in Boruto?

Tags: naruto

During the war, Naruto received all of the chakra natures along with the lava, magnet, and boil releases (and yin, yang, and yin-yang release). I've watched Naruto Shippuden completely and Boruto (to the current episode) but I haven't read any manga, so I was wondering if it was ever revealed if Naruto still has those chakra natures or if they were only because

> he had all of the jinchuriki in him

Also, what chakra natures does he currently have access to?

Comment: If he is back to basic it should be wind again but lets see

Comment: Naruto can control all chakra natures I believe, he just has a natural affinity towards wind chakra, as shown in the test with the chakra paper. It showed Sasuke to have an affinity for lightning chakra but he still has no problems creating a huge fireball jutsu.

Comment: @Gravinco Is there any proof that he can still control all chakra natures (How do we know if his powers over the chakra natures were temporary only because of the tailed beasts or not)

Comment: @JohnD After the fourth great ninja war Naruto was 'allowed' to keep a piece of chakra from each tailed beast so that they could use Naruto as a platform to communicate. Also, in the latest Boruto chapter we can see Naruto using an earth wall which we have never seen him use before. I based my previous comment on this.

Comment: @JohnD  Should I provide English translation for entire entry as well?

Comment: If you can @AbhishekMishra

Comment: well why not, but that will make post long. I hope that's not a problem.

Comment: @AbhishekMishra of course not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, in the Fourth Databook, which contains all data of Naruto by Kishimoto himself, lists following aspects of Naruto as a Shinobi

1.)Fire Element
2.)Wind Element 
3.)Lightning Element
4.)Earth Element
5.)Water Element
6.)Yin- Yang Release
7.)Yang Release
8.)Kekkei Genkai user

Here's a pic for reference :
[image: How to read this panel]
[image: Naruto's Databook Entry 1]
[image: Naruto's Databook Entry 2]

Translation : ( Not 100% accurate)
*All credit to OrganicDinosaur*
[OrganicDinosaur](https://www.narutoforums.org/members/organicdinosaur.246513/)

**Part 1: (pic 2)**

Ninja ID # = 012607
Birthday: 10/10 (Age 17, Libra)
Height: 166.0cm
Weight: 50.9 kg
Blood Type: B
Personality: 負けず嫌い (Hates to lose)、目立ちたがり (Exhibitionist (/someone who's a show-off, doing things to catch other people's attention)

Favourite:

木の葉の名店,一楽ラーメンが大のお気に入り。とんこつミソチヤーシューがブーム!
As a well-known restaurant in Konoha, Ichiraku Ramen is his most favourite thing! The 'Tonkotsu Miso Chiyashu' is a boom! (/All the rage!)

Village Affiliation: Konoha
Rank: Kage
Natures: All five basic elements + Yang
Icons: Jinchuuriki, Senjutsu, Kekkei-Genkai (Bloodline Limit), Kuchiyose (Summoning)

**Splash Text:**

オレはどの先代も超える火影になる！！それがオレの夢だ！！！
I will become a Hokage who will even surpass all the previous generations of Hokage!! That is my dream!!!

**Big Splash Text:**

うずまく乱世に凛と立ち戮力同心、平和を目指す！！
Standing united for a common cause. Bracing himself amidst the whirling and turbulent times: aiming for peace!!

『里の奴ら全員に、オレの存在を認めさせてやるん だ！』。。。第七班の結成時に、仲間達に誓った大いなる夢は、今や現実のものとなりつつある。自来也との修 業や「暁」と の激闘を経て、ナルトは確実に成長を遂げた。元来の豊かな発想力に加え、師と 同じ「仙術」や、尾獣とリンク した「完全なる人柱力」の力も 手に入れた。だがナルトの真価は別にある。それは仲間を信じ、 認め合い、共に戦う「絆」の力。 火影になるために最も重要な力 を、ナルトは身に着けたのだ!!

"I will make everybody in the village acknowledge my existence!!".When Team 7 was formed, he swore a great dream to his comrades. Now, he was in the process of making it a reality. By training with Jiraiya and battling fiercely with "Akatsuki", Naruto certainly achieved growth and maturity. In addition to primarily being full of expressive power and inventiveness, he also possessed the same "Senjutsu" as his master. Naruto even obtained the power (of being a)"Perfect Jinchuuriki" because of being linked to his Tailed-Beast. However, the true value of Naruto is apart from (those qualities). (The real worth of Naruto is from having) the power of faith in his comrades, mutual acceptance (/respect for one another), and the strength of Bonds while fighting together. These were the most important powers for Naruto to have within himself in order to become the Hokage!!

**Top Caption:**

ナルトの援護に忍び五大国の強者が集う! これぞ史上最強の忍術なのだ 。
In support of Naruto, the strongest shinobi from the Five Great Nations assemble! They will (surely be unleashing) the strongest ninjutsu in history!

**Bottom Right Caption:**

自来也譲りのド根性。 どんな困難な状況でも、 決して希望は捨てない。
Inheriting Jiraiya's utter gutsiness: No matter how difficult the situation will be, never abandon hope.

**Bottom Left Caption:**

歴代人柱力の中でも、九喇嘛と同調できたのはナルトだけ!
Although he had been inside successive generations of Jinchuuriki, Kurama could only sympathize (and conform) to Naruto!

**Special Box**

4年前: 終末の谷での大激戦！！
Four Years Ago: A huge, fierce battle at the Valley of the End!!

抜け忍になったサスケを連れ戻すべく、決死の説得！！
With persuasion that prepared him for death, Naruto (fought) in order to bring back Sasuke, who became a nukenin!!

**Side Splash Text**

師より授かりし唯一二の「名」と「心」。。。
He was given two unique things from his master: a "name" and a "heart"...

痛みと憎しみ
Pain and Hatred

妙木山の修業で?仙術?を修得したナルトは、その力を以て、師・自来也の仇ペインに挑む！！強敵相手に善戦 するナルトだが、戦いの最中にペインの抱えた痛みを知る。復讐。。。親しき者を殺された怒りは、師を失った ナルトにも理解し得るものだった?
By training at Mount Myoboku, Naruto learned Senjutsu. With that power, Naruto challenges his master's enemy: Pain!! He put up a good fight as a formidable enemy against Naruto. However, in the midst of battle, Naruto understood the pain that Pain possessed. It was for revenge. Pain was angry that someone close to him had been killed. Naruto was also able to sympathize (with him and his anger), since he had lost his master.

**Top Caption**

厳しい修業の末、ナルトは自来也以上に ?仙人モード? ?を極めた。
At the end of his relentless training, Naruto had mastered a "Sennin-Mode" beyond that of Jiraiya's.

**Middle Caption**

戦闘力は大幅に向上。たった一人でぺイン六道と渡り合う。
His fighting power had greatly improved. All by himself, Naruto exchanged blows with the Six Paths of Pain.

託されしもの
Something Entrusted to Him

仲間を倒されたナルトの怒りに呼応し、九尾が暴走。混濁する意識の中、現れたのは父だった。ナルトは自身の 迷いを吐露し、 父に問う。憎しみの連鎖を止める方法を。 答えは?出なかった。 だが授かったものはある。 それは「信頼」だった?。
Naruto's comrades were defeated. In response to his anger (about that situation), the Kyuubi rampaged. Within Naruto's clouded consciousness, his father appeared. Naruto expressed his own hesitations. He asked his father for a means to stop the chain of hatred. No answer came forth (from Minato).However, Naruto received something (from his father): Trust.

**Bottom Caption**

「お前ならその答えを見つけられる」。 父は木ノ葉の未来を、 ナルトに託した?！！
?If it?s you, you?ll be able to find that answer?. His father entrusted the future of Konoha to Naruto?!!

ド根性忍伝
The Tale of the Utterly Gutsy Ninja

最後のペインを打ち倒し、 ついにナルトは本体・ 長門に辿り着く。仇を前に、 選択を迫られるナルト。復讐を成すか、それとも?！？長門が受けた「痛み」を聞き、その上でナルトが出した 結論は。。。「和解」。どんなに「痛み」が伴なおうとも、どれほどの障害が待ち受けようとも、真の平和を諦 めない。それが「ナルト」と言う名に師が込めた想いだから。 ナルトの強き意志は、憎しみに満ちた長門の心をも動かした。
After defeating the last (path of) Pain, Naruto finally manages to arrive at the true body (of Pain): Nagato. In front of the enemy, Naruto was forced to make a choice: to either achieve revenge, or (to do something else)?.!? Naruto listened to the "pain" that Nagato had experienced. In addition, Naruto made a decision about (how to) conclude (the situation): "Reconciliation". No matter how much "pain" would certainly accompany him, and no matter how many obstacles awaited him?. Naruto would not abandon (trying to achieve) genuine peace. Those were Jiraiya's thoughts (for the meaning behind) the name "Naruto". Naruto's strong will then swayed the heart of Nagato, who was filled with hatred.

**Top Caption**

人々が本当の意味で 理解し合える時代 。真の平和を疑わず目指す。
Aiming for an era when everyone would truly be able to understand each other: Naruto had no doubts about genuine peace.

**Middle Caption**

ナルトの真っ直ぐな眼と言葉は、 新たな未来の可能性を予感させた。
With his direct gaze and words, Naruto foreshadowed the possibility of a new future.

英雄
Hero

師匠からは「名前」と 「諦めないド根性」を。 兄弟子からは、「痛み」を。 数々の想いと信頼を受け、ナルトは前へと歩む。そして、里に戻ったナルトを待っていたのは、 思わぬ歓迎だった?。 いたずらで皆の気を引く少年はもういない。 皆に信頼される、本物の英雄がそこにいた。
From his master, Naruto was given his "name" and "the utter gutsiness to not give up". From (his master's) senior disciple, Naruto was given pain. As Naruto accepts the trust and thoughts (of many people), he walks forward. And so, when Naruto returned to the village, the people were waiting for him. It was an unexpected reception(/welcome back)...He was no longer the boy who caused mischief (in order to) attract everyone else's attention. (Naruto was now) a true hero who was trusted by everyone.

**Bottom Right Caption**

小南は平和を願った弥彦と長門の想いを、ナルトに託した。
Konan entrusted Naruto with the thoughts of Yahiko and Nagato. They had all desired peace.

**Bottom Left Caption**

誰もに認められたい。ナルトの想いは皆に伝わり始めた。
He wanted to be recognized by everybody. Naruto's thoughts and feelings began to reach everyone.

**PART 2: (PIC 3)**

**Side Splash Text**

ナルトを強く。。。眩く。。。輝かせる
繋がり拡がる「絆」の輪。。。
Powerfully and brilliantly shining for Naruto…
A connected and extended circle of “Bonds”…

Sakura// サクラ
ナルトがサクラと交わした「一 生の約束」。それは、サスケを里 へ連れ帰ること。だが今や、そ れは二人の共通目標でもある。サスケのために切磋琢磨する二人の間には、希望も絶望も共に分かち合える、「 第七班の絆」 が確かに存在しているのだ。。。！！
Naruto exchanged “The promise of a lifetime”with Sakura. That pact was to bring Sasuke back home to the village. But now, it was also a common objective for the two of them. In order to (bring Sasuke back), both of them diligently applied their skills and cultivated their own personalities by working hard. While (they were training),they could share in their hope and despair with one another. “The bonds of Team 7” certainly exist…!!

**Top Caption:**

サクラの突然の告白。だが、ナルトはその奥に隠された想いに気づく。
It’s Sakura’s abrupt confession of love. However, Naruto noticed those feelings that were concealed behind (her words).

Gaara // 我愛羅
ナルトにとって、我愛羅は同じ痛みを知る者であり、里の垣根を超えた友でもある。そんな彼の言葉はナルトの 心に深く響く。 友として、サスケのために何が できるか。戦友の心からの助言を、ナルトは強くかみしめた。
Since Gaara was someone who understood the same pain as Naruto, (their friendship) transcended through the boundaries of the village. The words of such a guy deeply resounded within Naruto’s heart. As (Naruto’s) friend, what could he do for Sasuke’s sake. Naruto strongly reflected upon the advice from his fellow comrade’s heart.

**Middle Caption:**

サスケの「友」として、自分は何ができるのか。。。答えはナルト自身が出すしかない。
As Sasuke’s “Friend”, what could he personally do for him?... Naruto had no choice but to give that answer on his own.

Sasuke // サスケ
「終末の谷」「大蛇丸のアジト」 ――幾度かのナルトの説得も、 サスケには届かなかった。一流の忍になったニ人が拳を合わせ、 そして見えた心の内...!! もはやニ人は拳で分かり合うしかない。 ナルトはサスケと戦い、憎しみ全てを受け止める覚悟を決めた。
At “The Valley of the End” and “Orochimaru’s Hide-out” ――(No matter) how many times Naruto persuaded him, (his thoughts) did not even reach Sasuke. The two of them had become top-notch shinobi. By joining fists, what were they then able to see within (eachother’s) hearts…! (By exchanging blows), already the two of them had no other choice but to understand (one another). As Naruto fought with Sasuke, he prepared himself to receive all of his hatred.

**Bottom Right Caption**

大切な繋がりを守るため、命を懸ける。。。！！
In order to protect their bond, he risked his life…

**Bottom Left Caption**

サスケとは自分が戦う! ナルトの中には、揺るぎない覚悟ができていた。
He fought with Sasuke by himself! Within Naruto, he was able to uphold a solid resolution (to shoulder Sasuke’s burdens).

Killer Bee// キラービー
人柱力のナルトにとって、理想の姿はビーと八尾の関係そのもの。互いに心を通わせ、冗談を言っ て笑いあう。 ナルトはビーとの修業で人柱力の力の使い方と共に、目指すべ き「絆」の育み方も学んだ。
Since Naruto is a Jinchuuriki (he should strive to have the) relationship as (the bond between) between Bee and the Hachibi. Their connection was the ideal figure itself (of what should be between the host and Jinchuuriki). Going back and forth with each other in their minds, they tell jokes and laugh together. By training together with Bee, Naruto learned about the usage of the power of his Jinchuuriki. In addition, Naruto aimed for a way to elevate their “Bond”.

**Middle Caption**

ノリノリで拳を合わす、 奇妙な師弟関係が生まれた ...!!
In high-spirits, they bump fists. A strange teacher-student relationship was born...!!

Iruka // イルカ
ナルトにとって、イルカは初めての理解者であり、常に心に在り続ける存在。 戦場へと向かうナルトへ贈られたイルカの言葉は、数々の激闘の中でナルトの支えになった！！
Iruka was the first person to be understanding towards Naruto, so (Naruto) always continues to keep (Iruka’s) being within his heart. As Naruto headed towards the battlefield, Iruka conferred a few words to him. During many fierce battles, (Iruka’s thoughts) became support for Naruto!!

**Bottom Right Caption**

恩師の想いを胸に、いざ戦場へ！！
With his former teacher’s thoughts in his chest, (Naruto) now heads towards the battlefield!!

Kurama//九喇嘛
幼少期、周囲に拒絶されてきたナルトは、九尾の憎しみが理解できた。今はもうバケ狐じゃな い。ナルトは「九喇嘛」の名を呼び、呪われし心の封を解いた。
Since Naruto was rejected throughout his childhood (by the village), he was able to understand the Kyuubi’s hatred. Now, he was no longer the ‘Bakekitsune” (Monster Fox). When Naruto called out the name“Kurama”, the seal of the cursed heart would then become untied.

**Top Caption**

もはや駆け引きは不要！ 真に心で分かり合えたのだ。
Haggling is no longer necessary! They could truly understand each other’s hearts.

Kushina//クシナ
人柱力の修業中、ナルトは精神の中で母と会う。 母は修業の手助けと共に、大切なものを遺した。 それは愛。 強き想いは ナルトに、大いなる力を与える。
During his training with his Jinchuuriki, he met his Mother within his soul. Along with helping him with his training, his Mother left behind something important (to Naruto): her love. Those strong thoughts granted Naruto a huge (amount of) strength.

**Middle Caption:**

感極まる母との邂逅は、ナルトの心を晴れやかに！！
He had chance meeting with his Mother, who was overcome with emotion. Naruto’s heart was radiantly refreshed!!

Itachi//イタチ
仲間を忘れ個に執着すれば、 必ず失敗する。 戦いの業を全て背負おうとしていたナルトは、イ タチの戒めの言葉を、深く胸に刻む。
‘If one forgets comrades, and becomes attached to “the individual”, one will certainly fail.’ Naruto was trying to be burdened with all of the aspects of the battle. He then engraved Itachi’s words of caution deeply into his chest.

**Bottom Left Caption**

仲間に認められてこそ火影なのだ。
If one is recognized by his comrades, (that person) will surely be the Hokage.

**Side Splash Text**

託されしものを一心に受け「和」を以て悪夢を払わん
They wholeheartedly accept the things that were entrusted to them. They then dispose of the nightmare through "Peace".

仲間と共に
Together with Comrades

波乱うずまく第四次忍界大戦。 「個」の力が突出したマダラとオビトに対し、ナルトは「絆」の力で立ち向かう。 仲間達との「繋がり」こそが、巨大なる力に打ち勝つ術だと信じるからだ。仲間達の 援護、そして伝わる熱き「想い」が、ナルトに大きな力を与える ――ナルトを以て＂無限月読＂をも超えると言わしめた、 ”忍連合の術” が、ここに完成した。
The Fourth Great Ninja War was tumultuously whirling. Facing the power of the“Individual”that Madara and Obito pushed forth, Naruto opposed them with the power of “Bonds”. With his“Connection” to his comrades, he surely believed in them (in order for them to unleash) a jutsu to overcome a huge force. With the support of his comrades and through the feverish “Feelings” that they conveyed to him, Naruto granted them a great power. Naruto he made them say that (they could) even surpass the“Infinite Tsukuyomi”with the “Shinobi Alliance Jutsu”. It was completed (on the battlefield).

**Top Caption**

ナルトの盾となり散ったネジの想いも一緒に！九喇嘛チャクラを仲間に渡して、一丸となり戦う！ ！
Neji became a shield for Naruto and died a noble death! As well as dispersing Neji’s thoughts and feelings, Naruto was transferring Kurama’s chakra to his comrades. They will fight as one with solidarity!!

**Middle Caption**

目指すものは違えど敵は同じ！久方ぶりの共闘が実現した。
Their objectives were different, but their enemy was the same! They became a nostalgic, united front!

第七班 再び
Once Again, They Become Team 7

大蛇丸の ”穢土転生” で復活した歴代火影と共に、うちはサスケが戦線参加。ナルト、サクラ、 そしてサスケ…約四年の時を経て、木ノ葉の第七班は復活した。 それぞれの思惑はありつつも、 里を守ることに変わりはない。 力を合わせて共闘する第七班は、 空白の時を感じさせぬほどに、 絶妙な連携を見せるのだった。
Together with the former generations of Hokage, who were resurrected by Orochimaru’s “Edo-Tensei”, Uchiha Sasuke participated on the war-front. Naruto, Sakura, and then Sasuke….approximately four years had elapsed. It was the comeback of Konoha’s Team 7. Even though each of them had their own opinions, it didn’t change (their will to) protect the village. Team 7 joined forces for a united front, to the extent where they could not feel that a blank space of time (had elapsed). They showed superb cooperation (with one another).

**Bottom Caption**

第七班に木ノ葉の同期達も出揃って、 懐かしき光景に。。。！！
Team 7 also appears all together with their peers from Konoha: it was a nostalgic scene…!!

**Side Splash Text**

九匹のケモノの名を呼ぶ「予言の子」
戦いの果てに望むものは――
The “Child of Prophecy” calls out the names of the nine beasts.
It’s someone who wishes for the end of conflict ――

忍道
His Ninja Way

仲間は裏切るかもしれない。戦争は再び繰り返されるかもしれない。それなのに、なぜ命を懸けてまで戦うのか ！？茨の道と知りながら、なぜそこを進むのか。 世に絶望したオビトの問いに、ナルトは己の「忍道」を示す。 自分の言葉は曲げない――その言葉通り、ナルトはどんな困難があろうとも、夢を諦めない。。。 ！ ナルトがめざしている「火影」 とは、その道のりが険しいと分かっていても、先導を切って歩いていく者だからだ！！
Perhaps your comrades may betray you. Perhaps wars may be repeated again. However, why do you risk your life to that extent for battle!? While knowing that it will be a thorny path, why do you advance (to the battlefields). Obito proposed a question as he was in despair about the world. Naruto pointed out his own “Ninja Way”. ‘I won’t go back on my words’――(He would quote it) verbatim, no matter the difficult (situation that he faced). He would not abandon his dream…! Naruto was aiming to be “Hokage”. Even though he knew that it would be a precipitous journey, Naruto was someone who would continue to walk (towards his goal) by cutting through with his leadership!!

**Top Caption**

夢は自分で掴むもの。ナルトは逃げないッ！！
A dream is something that he seizes by himself. Naruto will not run away!!

**Middle Caption**

幼き頃から貴き通してきた忍道は、今もなおナルトの根幹にある。
Even since when he was young, he nobly continued with his Ninja Way. Even now, it’s the basis for Naruto (and his beliefs)!!

選択
A Choice

「この戦いの果てに何を望む？」 六道仙人の問いかけに、ナルトは 「仲間を守りたい」と答えた。 目指す未来は見えている。 後は戦いに勝つだけ！力を授かったナルトは、再び戦場へ戻った！！
"At the end of this battle, what will you wish for?" The Rikudou Sennin posed this question. Naruto answered: “I want to protect my comrades”. He could see it as a future goal. After he just wins this battle! Naruto was bestowed with the power (of the Rikudou Sennin) . Once again, Naruto returns to the battlefield!!

**Bottom Right Caption**

アシュラと同様、仲間がナルトの力。
Just like Ashura, the strength of Naruto is through his comrades.

**Bottom Left Caption**

六道仙人の力を授かっ た「二人一組」で決戦へ！！
Having been imparted the powers of the Rikudou Sennin, the”Two-Man Cell (/Two-Man Team)” heads towards the decisive battle!!

Answer (score -2):

He has all of them because he is powerful and is the sage of six paths son and nine tails chakra. With that, it can absorb nature energy with the six paths. Since the six paths is the creator of ninjutsu, he probably had to have all the chakra releases. Also, nature energy is all element of nature, fire, water, sand.

Comment: "Since the six paths is the creator of ninjutsu, he **probably** had to have all the chakra releases"... why "probably"? Do you have any sources/references to backup your answer?

Comment: 1: He is not the son of The Sage of Six Paths ( Naruto had the chakra of The Sage for a period of time to fight with Kaguya), 2: The Sage did not create ninjutsu (his son Indora did, The Sage created Ninshou which is a different thing), 3: nature energy is not a collection of all of the chakra releases,